# If I get bumped off the last flight of the day, the airport closes at night, does the airline pay for hotel?

Tags: air-travel

The airline would put me on the earliest flight next morning, but do I get compensated for the night's stay.

Comment: Please mention airline and your route.

Comment: The route and airline are relevant because e.g. the [EU has specific minimum rules on compensation](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/index_en.htm).

Comment: Happened to me in Austria, got vouchers for hotel + dinner + breakfast.

Comment: Some creditcards provide good travel insurance, if you paid for the flights with a creditcard I would take a look at its policy to be sure!

Comment: This question seems clear, and has at least one good answer. The hold should be lifted.

Comment: It doesn't need to be more more specific. Lots of great questions have multiple answers covering different jurisdictions, for example.

Answer (score 12):

In the EU you have a right to accommodation and food if your flight is delayed by more than 4 hours. That includes being bumped from a flight. There are some narrow exceptions, but in general if your flight starts or ends in the EU then you are entitled to this support and additional monetary compensation.

[This website](http://www.moneysavingexpert.com/travel/flight-delays) has extensive details of the rules and your rights.

Comment: Almost right, except that flights that start outside the EU are covered only if the airline is based in the EU.

Answer (score 11):

It depends on your itinerary.  If you are just starting your flights for that leg they would likely do nothing on the assumption you will just go home and return in the morning.

If you are enroute from A to C and get bumped at your stopover at B, then they would most likely provide you with accommodations and perhaps meal vouchers (though meal vouchers rarely cover a decent meal at the hotel's restaurant).

This also depends a bit on why you are being bumped.  If it is not the airline's fault (weather related issue, etc) they might not do anything in either situation.

Comment: "If you are just starting your flights for that leg they would likely do nothing on the assumption you will just go home and return in the morning" This is not correct, source: personal experience. Even if it's the first leg of an itinerary, the airline have no basis on which to assume you live nearby. For instance, you could have travelled for hours from your home by train to the airport, you could even be a tourist who has stayed for weeks in the airport destination before booking onward flights. Both have happened to me, and I was put up in a hotel.

Comment: Same experience as @davnicwil exactly. An intercontinental flight had technical problems at departure, and we were given dinner+hotel+breakfast.

Comment: One does not simply go home and return in the morning :)

Comment: If it's an EU flight (covered by 261/2004), then they have to provide accommodation even if it's not their fault. Save your receipts!

Comment: @davnicwil - I have seen my share of flights canceled at the beginning without hotels, it depends on the airlines, country and itinerary. So both sides of the scenario are correct.  That is why I said "likely" as it is not absolute.  Read carefully before pronouncing absolute judgement yourself, as my statement is "correct" in many situations.

Comment: @Irked: to be fair I am indeed talking about the word "likely", not the statement itself. Apologies, I wasn't simply saying you are wrong - I probably didn't communicate that clearly. To rephrase - in my view it is incorrect to say that being asked to go home and return in the morning is the *likely* outcome in the majority of cases. I would say being put up for the night is the likely outcome :-)

Comment: @davnicwil - Experiences vary, with 40+ years of global business travel under my belt, I have been left to on my own after an initial flight is cancelled 80% of the time.  Perhaps you in the EU have had different experiences (especially with the EU's overbearing compensation rules).  The EU does things quite differently than what happens in North America, South America, Asia, Africa, the Pacific Islands. The OP didn't specify a destination, so one can't assume that EU-centric policies will apply, one has to look more globally.